# Separar consulta Mysql por columnas

Tags: mysql

Tengo una consulta Mysql donde necesito separar la columna nombre en:

- Nombre - Apellido Paterno - Apellido Materno

La columna esta guardada asi:

Soto Amenabar, Pedro Pablo

Esta consulta tengo:

```
SELECT
NOMBRE,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(NOMBRE, ',', -1) as NOMBRE,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NOMBRE, ',', 1), ' ', 1) as APELLIDOP,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NOMBRE, ',', 1), ' ', -1) as APELLIDOM
FROM nombre;
```

pero me retorna:

Pedro Pablo    Amenabar    Amenabar

Comment: Hola, he probado tu query y a mi me funciona bién, de hecho a priori parece todo correcto, `APELLIDOP` me devuelve "Soto"

Comment: Lo que ocurre en tu caso es un error a nivel de diseño. ¿Por qué no definiste una columna para `APELLIDOP` y otra para `APELLIDOM`? Ese es el núcleo del problema, sobre todo porque si no lo haces así jamás podrás llegar a una solución satisfactoria, hay quienes tienen 2,3,4 ... nombres y hay apellidos compuestos, a veces ambos, a veces el paterno, a veces el materno. Eso sólo se resuelve diferenciando cada dato en el origen. Imagina este caso: `María Natividad del Carmen de los Ángeles De la Calzada De Cospedal` ¿cómo estandarizas o encajas ese caso en cualquier código?